# Vim - Colorscheme leaves trailing black (whitespace) in random places

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Vim & NeoVim both leave patches of simply black text scattered in random locations across the viewport. This is most common when scrolling or jumping between locations. This affect has happened on multiple different colorschemes so I suspect its more a problem with vim or my shell, than with the scheme. Generally when I load a file these patches don't exist, but they appear pretty quickly after starting vim. Reloading my configuration file or changing the scheme definitely makes them appear. Restarting the shell or quitting and restarting vim doesn't have any affect.

I'm running windows build 17763.92 on windows 10 Education & vim/neovim on Ubuntu (version 18.04 Bionic) bash for windows under the WSL.

Could anyone enlighten me as to why this is happening?

Heres my [vim version info](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iwWRDquSGpHHs3pJgzui_aMGOfn2d8Kh).

Heres my [vimrc](https://gist.github.com/MoHKale/b3306816a265cc48e7ec421a9b3e5da2) File & A [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ka_iw121iAspfyDQj53XHnxOCZ4rzZjF) of The Described Affect.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by a wrong terminal setting in `$TERM`. The commands that Vim sends to the terminal to clear it then don't properly set the background color, and only text written on top has the correct background.

If you don't find a fix for that, you can work around the problem by clearing the background color of the `Normal` highlight group:

```
:hi Normal ctermbg=NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, I would get black highlighting when opening a new line using o or O, and it would also appear when paging down (ctrl D) then scrolling up (k).

I was using vim (.vimrc - colorscheme desert with syntax on) on windows ubuntu subsystem WSL.

I was able to make it go away by updating my Windows 10 version 1909, to Windows 10 version 2004.

My problem was similar to this post: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21437/vim-is-highlights-everything-after-eol-in-yellow-upon-scrolling

and, someone had also mentioned it being related to the terminal type xterm-256color here (their recommendation was to upgrade Windows version, it worked for me): https://superuser.com/questions/1526515/vim-highlighting-newlines-in-a-file-how-to-disable